# What libraries are available for Histogram Equalization of an Image?

Tags: image-processing, histogram

I am having a hard time finding a library that will preform [Histogram equalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) of an Image.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) and I believe you're looking for [cvEqualizeHist](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/image_processing.html?highlight=cvequalizehist#cvEqualizeHist)

Answer (score 1):

I don't claim to be an expert, but Wikipedia has [this link](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/image_processing.html#histograms) to the OpenCV library; the histogram functions there appear pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've used Aforge.Net
[link text](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/)